# Change the 404 redirect page from default page to custom page.

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I am trying to have a custom redirect page for 404 errors. At the moment there is a different error page from the host server maybe, My web.config file is below. when I comment out the customError tags the default page from the host server shows up I want to change this to a custom page "404.html". When I uncomment this out it probably tries to override the default but gives an internal server error!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    Please refer to machine.config.comments for a description and
    the default values of each configuration section.

    For a full documentation of the schema please refer to
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=42127

    To improve performance, machine.config should contain only those
    settings that differ from their defaults.

<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <customErrors mode="On">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.html" />
        </customErrors>
        <!--<httpErrors> 
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />                
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />          
      </httpErrors>-->       
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is it the Integrated/ pipeline mode thing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 declaration doesn't go in the customErrors tag, here is what you should need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Try setting your `web.config` to just that and see if it works, the customErrors tag is more for .NET pages than classic ASP, even the classic `500:100` is declares in the `httpErrors` section and not in the `CustomErrors`.

This is taken from a known working `web.config` with irrelevant bits stripped out.  You can send it to an ASP page as you are using `ExecuteURL`, meaning you can handle 404s smartly, e.g. redirect or offer a search results page.